# Fatal server errors, no screens found

Tags: 12.04, xorg

I am an issue with my ubuntu box: I get the following error message when I do a startx: `Fatal server errors, no screens found`

When I start my computer, I do hear the ubuntu sound indicating the system is awaiting for a user session to be opened but the screen is black...

What is more I can't find anything relevant in the Xorg.0.log...

I have copied it here:

Xorg.0.log:

```
[    77.084] 
X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
[    77.084] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    77.084] Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-34-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    77.084] Current Operating System: Linux alpha 3.2.0-38-generic #61-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 19 12:18:21 UTC 2013 x86_64
[    77.085] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-38-generic root=UUID=3501b573-9d6b-4ef2-bfec-fdf79842cf61 ro recovery nomodeset
[    77.085] Build Date: 17 January 2013  06:14:10AM
[    77.085] xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.11 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    77.085] Current version of pixman: 0.24.4
[    77.085]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    77.085] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    77.086] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Feb 23 19:26:56 2013
[    77.099] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    77.099] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    77.099] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    77.099] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    77.099] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    77.099] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    77.099] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    77.099] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    77.099] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    77.099]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    77.099] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    77.099]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    77.099] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    77.099]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    77.099] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    77.099]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    77.099] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    77.099]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    77.099] (WW) The directory "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType" does not exist.
[    77.099]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    77.099] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    77.099] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    77.099] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    77.099] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f259f2c8b00
[    77.099] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    77.099]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    77.099]    X.Org Video Driver: 11.0
[    77.099]    X.Org XInput driver : 16.0
[    77.099]    X.Org Server Extension : 6.0
[    77.103] (--) PCI:*(0:7:0:0) 10de:0165:10de:0334 rev 161, Mem @ 0xfa000000/16777216, 0xd0000000/268435456, 0xfb000000/16777216, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    77.103] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[    77.103] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[    77.103] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
[    77.103] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    77.103]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    77.103]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    77.103]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    77.103] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    77.103] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    77.103] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
[    77.103] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[    77.103] (II) Loading extension XVideo
[    77.103] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    77.103] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
[    77.103] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[    77.104] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
[    77.104] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    77.104]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    77.104]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    77.104]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    77.104] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    77.104] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    77.104] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[    77.120] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    77.120]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    77.120]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    77.120] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  295.40  Thu Apr  5 21:57:38 PDT 2012
[    77.120] (II) Loading extension GLX
[    77.120] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[    77.120] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
[    77.120] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    77.120]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.13.0
[    77.120]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    77.120]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    77.120] (II) Loading extension RECORD
[    77.120] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[    77.121] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[    77.121] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    77.121]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    77.121]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    77.121] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
[    77.121] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    77.121] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[    77.121] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    77.121]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.2.0
[    77.121]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    77.121] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[    77.121] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    77.121] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[    77.121] (==) Matched nv as autoconfigured driver 2
[    77.121] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[    77.121] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 4
[    77.121] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    77.121] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    77.121] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    77.206] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    77.206]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    77.206]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    77.231] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    77.231] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    77.244] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    77.244]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.0.16
[    77.244]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    77.244]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[    77.244] (II) LoadModule: "nv"
[    77.244] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nv
[    77.244] (II) UnloadModule: "nv"
[    77.244] (II) Unloading nv
[    77.244] (EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)
[    77.244] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    77.244] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    77.244] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    77.244]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 2.3.0
[    77.244]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    77.244]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[    77.244] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    77.245] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    77.254] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    77.254]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.4.2
[    77.254]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[    77.254] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    77.254] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[    77.254] (==) Matched nv as autoconfigured driver 2
[    77.254] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[    77.254] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 4
[    77.254] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    77.254] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    77.254] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    77.254] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    77.254]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    77.254]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    77.254] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    77.254] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    77.254] (II) Failed to load module "nvidia" (already loaded, 32549)
[    77.254] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    77.254] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    77.254] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    77.254]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.0.16
[    77.254]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    77.254]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[    77.254] (II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
[    77.254] (II) Unloading nouveau
[    77.254] (II) Failed to load module "nouveau" (already loaded, 32549)
[    77.254] (II) LoadModule: "nv"
[    77.255] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nv
[    77.255] (II) UnloadModule: "nv"
[    77.255] (II) Unloading nv
[    77.255] (EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)
[    77.255] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    77.255] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    77.255] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    77.255]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 2.3.0
[    77.255]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    77.255]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[    77.255] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    77.255] (II) Unloading vesa
[    77.255] (II) Failed to load module "vesa" (already loaded, 0)
[    77.255] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    77.255] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    77.255] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    77.255]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.4.2
[    77.255]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[    77.255] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    77.255] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    77.255] (II) Failed to load module "fbdev" (already loaded, 0)
[    77.255] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  295.40  Thu Apr  5 21:38:35 PDT 2012
[    77.255] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    77.265] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Wed Nov 30 18:56:54 2011 +0100
[    77.265] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[    77.265]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[    77.265]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[    77.265]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[    77.265]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[    77.265]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[    77.265]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[    77.265]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[    77.265]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[    77.265]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[    77.265]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[    77.265]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[    77.265]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[    77.265]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[    77.265] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    77.265] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    77.265] (--) using VT number 2

[    77.269] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    77.269] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    77.269] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    77.282] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    77.282]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    77.282]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    77.282] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[    77.282] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[    77.283] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    77.296] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    77.296]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    77.296]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    77.296] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    77.296] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    77.296] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    77.302] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    77.302] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    77.302] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    77.322] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    77.322] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    77.322] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    77.322] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    77.322] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    77.334] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    77.334]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.0.2
[    77.334]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[    77.334] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[    77.334] (II) NVIDIA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    77.334] (==) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    77.334] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[    77.334] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    77.334] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    77.334] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[    79.036] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Unable to read EDID for display device CRT-0
[    79.118] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (DELL E228WFP (DFP-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[    79.118] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[    79.120] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU Quadro NVS 285 (NV44GL) at PCI:7:0:0 (GPU-0)
[    79.120] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 131072 kBytes
[    79.120] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 05.44.02.63.03
[    79.120] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[    79.120] (--) NVIDIA(0): Interlaced video modes are supported on this GPU
[    79.120] (--) NVIDIA(0): Connected display device(s) on Quadro NVS 285 at PCI:7:0:0
[    79.120] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-0
[    79.120] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DELL E228WFP (DFP-1)
[    79.120] (--) NVIDIA(0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    79.120] (--) NVIDIA(0): DELL E228WFP (DFP-1): 155.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    79.120] (--) NVIDIA(0): DELL E228WFP (DFP-1): Internal Single Link TMDS
[    79.120] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    79.120] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device CRT-0 (Using EDID frequencies has been enabled on
[    79.120] (**) NVIDIA(0):     all display devices.)
[    79.120] (II) NVIDIA(0): Assigned Display Device: CRT-0
[    79.120] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    79.120] (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[    79.120] (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
[    79.120] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    79.120] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated modes:
[    79.120] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "nvidia-auto-select"
[    79.120] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1024 x 768
[    79.121] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device CRT-0's EDID; cannot compute DPI
[    79.121] (WW) NVIDIA(0):     from CRT-0's EDID.
[    79.121] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (75, 75); computed from built-in default
[    79.121] (II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
[    79.121] (II) Unloading nouveau
[    79.121] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    79.121] (II) Unloading vesa
[    79.121] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    79.121] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    79.121] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    79.121] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[    79.121] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    79.128] (II) NVIDIA(0): ACPI: failed to connect to the ACPI event daemon; the daemon
[    79.128] (II) NVIDIA(0):     may not be running or the "AcpidSocketPath" X
[    79.128] (II) NVIDIA(0):     configuration option may not be set correctly.  When the
[    79.128] (II) NVIDIA(0):     ACPI event daemon is available, the NVIDIA X driver will
[    79.128] (II) NVIDIA(0):     try to use it to receive ACPI event notifications.  For
[    79.128] (II) NVIDIA(0):     details, please see the "ConnectToAcpid" and
[    79.128] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "AcpidSocketPath" X configuration options in Appendix B: X
[    79.128] (II) NVIDIA(0):     Config Options in the README.
[    79.128] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[    79.224] (II) Loading extension NV-GLX
[    79.262] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[    79.262] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store disabled
[    79.262] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    79.263] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[    79.263] (II) Loading extension NV-CONTROL
[    79.263] (II) Loading extension XINERAMA
[    79.263] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    79.263] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    79.263] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[    79.263] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    79.263]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.2.0
[    79.263]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    79.263] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    79.263] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[    79.263] (==) RandR enabled
[    79.263] (II) Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[    79.263] (II) Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[    79.263] (II) Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[    79.263] (II) Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[    79.263] (II) Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[    79.263] (II) Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[    79.263] (II) Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[    79.263] (II) Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[    79.263] (II) Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[    79.263] (II) Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[    79.263] (II) Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[    79.263] (II) Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[    79.263] (II) Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[    79.263] (II) Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[    79.263] (II) Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[    79.264] (II) Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[    79.265] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[    79.471] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[    79.488] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[    79.488] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    79.488] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[    79.488] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    79.520] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    79.520]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 2.7.0
[    79.520]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    79.520]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 16.0
[    79.520] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    79.520] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    79.520] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    79.520] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[    79.520] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    79.520] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    79.520] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    79.520] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1/event1"
[    79.520] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    79.520] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    79.520] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    79.520] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "fr"
[    79.520] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "latin9"
[    79.521] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-816A055A5FF7D63897839A4BDEDC3908551E49DA.xkm
[    79.532] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[    79.532] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    79.532] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    79.532] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    79.532] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    79.532] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[    79.532] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    79.532] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    79.532] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    79.532] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0"
[    79.532] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    79.532] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    79.532] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    79.532] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "fr"
[    79.532] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "latin9"
[    79.532] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Line (/dev/input/event5)
[    79.532] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    79.532] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    79.533] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Mic (/dev/input/event6)
[    79.533] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    79.533] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    79.533] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Front Headphone (/dev/input/event7)
[    79.533] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    79.533] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    79.533] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Line-Out (/dev/input/event8)
[    79.533] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    79.533] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    79.533] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/event2)
[    79.533] (**) USB Optical Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    79.533] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'USB Optical Mouse'
[    79.533] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    79.533] (**) USB Optical Mouse: always reports core events
[    79.533] (**) evdev: USB Optical Mouse: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[    79.533] (--) evdev: USB Optical Mouse: Vendor 0x461 Product 0x4d15
[    79.533] (--) evdev: USB Optical Mouse: Found 3 mouse buttons
[    79.533] (--) evdev: USB Optical Mouse: Found scroll wheel(s)
[    79.533] (--) evdev: USB Optical Mouse: Found relative axes
[    79.533] (--) evdev: USB Optical Mouse: Found x and y relative axes
[    79.534] (II) evdev: USB Optical Mouse: Configuring as mouse
[    79.534] (II) evdev: USB Optical Mouse: Adding scrollwheel support
[    79.534] (**) evdev: USB Optical Mouse: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    79.534] (**) evdev: USB Optical Mouse: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    79.534] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/input/input2/event2"
[    79.534] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "USB Optical Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 8)
[    79.541] (II) evdev: USB Optical Mouse: initialized for relative axes.
[    79.541] (**) USB Optical Mouse: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    79.541] (**) USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    79.541] (**) USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    79.541] (**) USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    79.541] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    79.541] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    79.541] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    79.542] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard (/dev/input/event3)
[    79.542] (**) Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    79.542] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard'
[    79.542] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    79.542] (**) Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: always reports core events
[    79.542] (**) evdev: Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[    79.542] (--) evdev: Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: Vendor 0x413c Product 0x2110
[    79.542] (--) evdev: Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: Found keys
[    79.542] (II) evdev: Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[    79.542] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-2/1-2.4/1-2.4:1.0/input/input3/event3"
[    79.542] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[    79.542] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    79.542] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    79.542] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "fr"
[    79.542] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "latin9"
[    79.542] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard (/dev/input/event4)
[    79.542] (**) Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    79.542] (**) Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    79.542] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard'
[    79.542] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    79.542] (**) Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: always reports core events
[    79.542] (**) evdev: Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[    79.542] (--) evdev: Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: Vendor 0x413c Product 0x2110
[    79.542] (--) evdev: Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: Found 9 mouse buttons
[    79.542] (--) evdev: Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: Found scroll wheel(s)
[    79.542] (--) evdev: Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: Found relative axes
[    79.542] (--) evdev: Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: Found x and y relative axes
[    79.542] (--) evdev: Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: Found keys
[    79.542] (II) evdev: Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: Configuring as mouse
[    79.542] (II) evdev: Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[    79.542] (II) evdev: Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: Adding scrollwheel support
[    79.542] (**) evdev: Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    79.542] (**) evdev: Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    79.542] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-2/1-2.4/1-2.4:1.1/input/input4/event4"
[    79.542] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[    79.542] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    79.542] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    79.542] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "fr"
[    79.542] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "latin9"
[    79.543] (II) evdev: Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: initialized for relative axes.
[    79.543] (**) Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    79.543] (**) Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    79.543] (**) Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    79.543] (**) Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    79.543] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Dell Dell Wired Multimedia Keyboard (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    79.543] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    79.543] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

Comment: Hello Eric. I have tried replacing "quiet splash" with "no splash". I have the same problem... Note that I am in the case of: "something else caused your boot problem".

Comment: You need to use `nomodeset` too.  See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/162076/44179).  If that doesn't fix the problem please [flag this for reopening.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/6072/44179)  Thanks!

Comment: thanks Seth. I sorted the problem by reinstalling the nvidia drivers in failsafe mode.

Comment: Okay, great.  That's what you would have needed to do after booting anyway ;)